# When the username contains Hebrew characters the timestamp of a comment is split in two

Tags: bug, status-completed, comments, design, hebrew

Looking at the comments of [this user](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/users/4484/?tab=activity&sort=comments), I noticed that the timestamp of the comment is written partially before the username, and partially after it.

> [image: screenshot]

Comment: I have a hunch that this doesn't apply to all UTF-8 characters, but rather to ones that are written right-to-left

Comment: But wouldn't it need an override then? Control characters are not allowed.

Comment: And repro here, FF8.

Comment: When RTL characters are displayed inside LTR text, and neighboring with neutral characters like numbers, you usually need to add a left-to-right or right-to-left mark to override the directionality. The proper solution here might be (?) to always display usernames using RTL script with automatically added directionality marks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We added `dir="ltr"` to the html, so this is fixed now. RTL display names were also displayed incorrectly when shown alongside the reputation number, and that's been fixed as well.

Comment: Booo does that mean this won't work anymore? ‮ Or does it? :-P