# Bold star count rolls over to user text numbers from starred chat content

Tags: bug, status-norepro, chat

Our users have been having fun with a display bug (or what looks like one to me) in the chat star display.

If you have a chat item that begins in a number, that leading number gets the bold treatment when displayed in the chat sidebar for starred content.

[image]

I can't see a reason why this would be a feature, but please enlighten me if that's the case. It seems only the star and the system count should be emboldened and not the user content itself.

[image]

Comment: Could that be the usage of right-to-left control characters? I remember something similar done to the comments ones.

Comment: Ah, here is one of them: [What is up with this comment timestamp?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/84296/what-is-up-with-this-comment-timestamp)

Comment: Should I just delete this since my characterization is incorrect - the users bolded the numbers so the system didn't add it or is this useful to have if others make the same mistake as I in assuming there might be a bug.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm pretty sure those users did the bolding themselves specifically to fool people, and this is not a bug. This was done in The Tavern on MSO chat years ago. Note that the five in "5 votes left for the day" is *not* bold.

Comment: Oh man - you are totally correct. I guess the bug is me ;-) Having some sort of demarkation between the user content and the bold system content would probably be a bad idea to inflict on all starred content...

Answer (score 2):

Amateurs.

Also, a good demonstration of how "hacking" can be as simple as exploiting appearance in a UI.

[image]

Comment: Social Engineering FTW

Comment: Wooow, I just gave your answer +5000 with Firebug! I iz 1337 hax0r!